# Four consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The product of four consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression of integers plus the fourth power of the common difference is always a perfect square. Verify this identity by incorporating symmetry into the notation.

I worked on this problem to solidify my heuristic for symmetry.

My solution is as follows:

$$(a_n-2d)(a_n-d)(a_n)(a_n+d)=a_n^4-2da_n^3-d^2a_n^2+2d^3a_n$$
Adding $d^4$  we have:
$$a_n^4-2da_n^3-d^2a_n^2+2d^3a_n+d^4$$
I substituted $x=a_n$ and I obtained 
$$x^4-2dx^3-d^2x^2+2d^3x+d^4=(x^2-dx^2-d^2)^2$$

But I feel like I didn't use symmetry and I missed the point of the problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

Just let common difference be $2d$, then

$(a-3d)(a-d)(a+d)(a+3d)+16d^4= a^4-10d^2a^2+25d^4 = (a^2-5d^2)^2$

Comment: In particular, the product is $(a^2-d^2)(a^2-9d^2)=(a^2-5d^2)^2-(4d^2)^2$.

Comment: ... and $a$ is the average of the four terms, which is actually halfway between the second and third terms.

Comment: Wait what if $d$ is odd? For instance $3,6,9,$ and $12$?

Comment: if the common difference is $3$, then $2d=3$, so $d=\dfrac32$; $d$ does not have to be an integer

Comment: Then how is $(a^2-5d^2)^2$ an integer?

Comment: $d$ has to be an integer, since it is an arithmetic progression of _integers_.

Comment: @AndrewChin:  in this answer, $2d$ (the common difference) must be an integer, but $d$ does not have to be

Comment: @crystal_math:  cf. your example $3, 6, 9, $ and $12$; for this answer, $a=\dfrac{15}2$ and $d=\dfrac32$; $a-3d, a-d, a+d, $ $a+3d$, and $a^2-5d^2$ are all integers even though $a$ and $d$ are not

Comment: Ahh makes sense though I will not accept the answer above since it didn't explain enough. And thank you J. W. Tanner for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Sorry I went offline. Consider the case when $2d$ is odd. Then since $a-d$ must be integer, we need $2a$ be odd. So in this case, $(2a)^2-(10d)^2$ is $(2a-10d)(2a+10d)$ so is multiple of $4$ therefore $a^2-5d^2$ is integer